# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at GitLab

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Since yesterday (without a change on config fails) I started to get error:
`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon`

Here is the snippet of the error:

```
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version:           20.10.7
API version:       1.41
Go version:        go1.13.15
Git commit:        f0df350
Built:             Wed Jun  2 11:56:47 2021
OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
Context:           default
Experimental:      true
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker
```

daemon running?

I am using Debian on the worker. Even with pure Docker setup (without any other config) docker daemon is not reachable.

Here is the gitlab-ci.yaml file:

```
before_script:
   - apt-get update -yqq
   - apt-get -y install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release
   - curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | gpg --dearmor -o 
   /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
   - echo \
       "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] 
        https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | tee 
             /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
   - apt-get update -yqq
   - apt-get -y install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
   - docker version
```

Each invocation of the `docker` cmd results in:
`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Facing kind of the same issue. In your case, a question. Are you sure that none of the packages you download during your script has changed? The fact that you didn't change things does not mean others also didn't..

Comment: Thanks, @Nebulosar I thought the same, that's why I try to change the version of the docker for something older as it is suggested on Docker official page:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/

Again without luck. It seems like either Docker engine hasn't started (although the service is running) or the user doesn't have permission (for some reason) to docker socket anymore.